# RoboGuice injected view is null

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, roboguice

I'm trying to figure out what could be wrong with my view injection.
It works for fragments in my application, but I can't seem to get it working for activity.
Here is my code:

```
@ContentView(R.layout.schedule)
public class ScheduleActivity extends RoboFragmentActivity{

   @InjectView(R.id.train_list_holder) ListView mViewTrainListContainer;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
       super.onCreate(arg0);
       CL.v(String.valueOf(mViewTrainListContainer));
   }
}
```

Value of mViewTrainListContainer is always null.

Comment: Could you add your layout xml?

Comment: Was going to copy my layout and just figured out my problem. I have LinearLayout not ListView. Strange that it wont throw any Cast exceptions. It just sets my var to null.

Answer (score 0):

Type of View was set wrong. It was LinearLayout, not ListView.